# No Audio from external monitor sound source after hibernate

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, external-monitor, output

I have a monitor and have connected my laptop to it through HDMI. I have enabled hibernate through the partition. Whenever the system comes up after hibernate the audio source of the monitor doesn't work. if I switch to the audio of the laptop it works fine. I have to reboot every time to enable the external monitor speaker. I tested it on another monitor of a different brand and the issue persists. Sometimes Chrome gives a video playback error.

Below is the DMESG output

```
ar@ar:~$ sudo dmesg | grep snd
[    3.110703] snd_rn_pci_acp3x 0000:08:00.5: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.308387] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.329583] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    3.329595] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: Force to non-snoop mode
[    3.330914] snd_hda_intel 0000:08:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.331177] snd_hda_intel 0000:08:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    3.331980] snd_hda_intel 0000:08:00.6: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.386873] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0: autoconfig for ALC245: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    3.386878] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.386881] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.386884] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.386886] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    inputs:
[    3.386888] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:      Mic=0x19
[    5.216189] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: bound 0000:03:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[    6.333356] snd_hda_intel 0000:08:00.1: bound 0000:08:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[  702.157295] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[  703.262000] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[  703.548524] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  761.377111] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[  761.659376] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  780.226485] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[  785.530237] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[  786.670842] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[  786.950040] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  870.969725] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[  871.257660] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  881.966099] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[  882.245173] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
```